# DIVs not applying alignment

Tags: html, css

I am not sure what is causing my issue with the DIV alignment. I am trying to get the two 2 column DIVs to align in the middle, but each of the container DIVs do not seem to be applying the alignment attributes. It appears each DIV container is only aligning to the left.

```css
.twoColumnV2 {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-width: auto;
  -moz-column-width: auto;
  column-width: auto;
}
.twoColumn {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  /* Firefox */
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  /* Firefox */
  column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-width: 50%;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -moz-column-width: 50%;
  /* Firefox */
  column-width: 50%;
}
.inlineBlock {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1 class="inlineBlock" style="margin-top:-5px">Test Format</h1>
</div>
<div class="twoColumn">
  <div style="text-align: right">
    <!-- DIV container 01 -->
    <div class="twoColumnV2 inlineBlock">
      <div style="text-align: right" class="fieldName inlineBlock">Commodity:</div>
      <div style="text-align: left" class="inlineBlock">
        <select name="fkTest">
          <option value="">Please select</option>
          <option value="1">Avocados</option>
          <option value="2">Beans</option>
          <option value="3">Berries</option>
          <option value="4">Broccoli</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="text-align: left">
    <!-- DIV container 02 -->
    <div class="twoColumnV2 inlineBlock">
      <div style="text-align:right" class="fieldName inlineBlock">Variety:</div>
      <div style="text-align:left" class="inlineBlock">
        <select name="fkLocTest" id="fkLocTest">
          <option value="">Please select</option>
          <option value="12">Beefsteak</option>
          <option value="11">Cherry</option>
          <option value="13">Cherry on the Vine Organic</option>
          <option value="14">Cluster</option>
          <option value="10">Grape</option>
          <option value="9">Roma</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jecker/fLr0h5c4/)

Comment: Why are you using columns?

Comment: To align all of the proceeding data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered using multiple column DIVs, all columns are the same width. Multi column DIVs do not allow for separate widths for each column. The solution is to change the layout and not use so many multi column DIVs.

Answer (score 0):

try this for the div: `twoColumn`

```
margin-left: 20%;
margin-right: 20%;
```

Comment: Nope, that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
.twoColumnV2 {
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
        -moz-column-gap: 20px;
        column-gap: 20px;
        -webkit-column-width: auto;
        -moz-column-width: auto;
        column-width: auto;
    }

    .twoColumn {
        -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
        column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-gap: 20px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-gap: 20px; /* Firefox */
        column-gap: 20px;
        -webkit-column-width: 50%; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-width: 50%; /* Firefox */
        column-width: 50%;
    }
    .float_left{float:left}
    .center{margin:0 auto; width:1170px;text-align:center}
    .flex{display:inline-flex;margin-right:50px}

</style>
      </head>

    <body>
    <div style="text-align:center"><h1 class="inlineBlock" style="margin-top:-5px">Test Format</h1></div>



    <div class="center">

    <div class="left_column flex">
     <div  class="fieldName">Commodity:</div>
                <div  class="inlineBlock">
                <select name="fkTest">
                    <option value="">Select Commodity:</option>
                    <option value="1">Avocados</option>
                    <option value="2">Beans</option>
                    <option value="3">Berries</option>
                    <option value="4">Broccoli</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                </div>







    <div class="right_column flex">

    <div  class="fieldName">Variety:</div>
                <div  class="inlineBlock">
                    <select name="fkLocTest" id="fkLocTest">
                        <option value="">Select Variety:</option>
                        <option value="12">Beefsteak</option>
                        <option value="11">Cherry</option>
                        <option value="13">Cherry on the Vine Organic</option>
                        <option value="14">Cluster</option>
                        <option value="10">Grape</option>
                        <option value="9">Roma</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                 </div>


    </div>
    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see the classes "left_column" and "right_column." Are you referring to float_left = left_column?

Comment: Hi Jecker, the classes for  "left_column" and "right_column." is not much important in this case

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, this solution:

```
.inlineBlock {
    display:inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

instead of just this:

```
.inlineBlock {
    display:inline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I use display:inline or display:inline-block?

Comment: look like with **inline**:
http://oi65.tinypic.com/an1wdk.jpg

and with **inline-block**:
http://oi67.tinypic.com/24y379v.jpg

(Tested with Firefox and Midori on Linux OS)